# Autodesk Forge API - Setting Scopes for data with read, write, and create

Tags: autodesk-forge

I initially created an app and starting developing it using only the data:read scope. I have now realized that I need the data:create scope as well.

1. Is there something within the app settings that I need to change?
2. Does the create scope include read permissions and then write scope include create and read - or does that scope have to be sent separately?
3. If separately, how is that done when the user is granting permission to the app? Is it something like &scope=data:read&scope:create
4. I don't have to store and then use two tokens, do I?
5. How is this handled when using curl? Are the read and create scopes sent in an array like so ...

   ```
   $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/gettoken', [
       'form_params' => [
           'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
           'code' => $authCode,
           'client_id' => $FusionID,
           'client_secret' => $FusionSecret,
           'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.example.com/fusionauth',
           'scope' => array('data'=>'create', 'data'=>'read')
       ]
   ]);
   ```

Again, it may be that you only use the scope you need and you have to store separate tokens, but that doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: OK. Played with this for a long time and it looks like &scope=data:read data:create

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something within the app settings that I need to change?

If by `app settings` you meant in the Forge App portal then you only have to specify there the APIs (make sure they are checked on the page) that your app will need to access.

> Does the create scope include read permissions and then write scope include create and read - or does that scope have to be sent separately?

No doesn't work like that - you will need to specify each one of them explicitly.

> If separately, how is that done when the user is granting permission to the app? Is it something like &scope=data:read&scope:create

Nope the scope variables are delimited by space. For 3-legged oauth you will need to obtain an authorization code through redirecting the user to authenticate at our login portal before you go for access tokens and there you will need to indicate the redirection address and scope combinations in the request URL (don't forget to URLEncode them) such as `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=obQDn8P0GanGFQha4ngKKVWcxwyvFAGE&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsampleapp.com%2Foauth%2Fcallback%3Ffoo%3Dbar&scope=data:read`. See [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token/) for details.

And check out our official [PHP client SDK](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-php-client) - should save you tons of effort and time.

> I don't have to store and then use two tokens, do I?

If your token carries sufficient permissions (say `data:read` and `data:create`) then no.

> How is this handled when using curl? Are the read and create scopes sent in an array like so ...

For cURL see samples here: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-2-legged-token/

And like we went through above you will need to specify the scopes when redirecting the user to authenticate so in your request to fetch the eventual access token you'd should something like:

```
$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/gettoken', [
     'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'code' => $authCode,
        'client_id' => $FusionID,
        'client_secret' => $FusionSecret,
        'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.example.com/fusionauth'
        )
    ]
]);
```

Comment: "scope variables are delimited by space". I don't understand this. How do you communicate that you are prompting for both the read and create scopes? &scope=data:read create is not a valid URL.

Comment: Like we went thru in my answer you can URLEncode them